# Am I computing the centralizer of $(1, 2, 3)$ in $A_4$ correctly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, permutations

From my understanding, the centralizer of a permutation $p$ can be computed by including the identity permutation $()$ and then finding all the equivalent ways to represent $p$ (which can be done by rearranging the order of the disjoint cycles and rearranging the elements within the disjoint cycles).

So what I get that the centralizer of $(1, 2, 3)$ is the set:

$S = \{(), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2)\}$

Is that correct?

Comment: NB: $$(123)=(231)=(312)$$ and $$(132)=(213)=(321).$$

Comment: @Shaun So if I exclude the permutations (132), (213), and (321) from my set, then I will get the correct answer, right?

Comment: The computed centralizer is correct but I'm not sure if I understand how you arrive at it - as in whether you're using the right result to deduce $S$. To be precise, what constraints do you place on $p$ and the underlying group?

Comment: @FernandoTorres Your answer is correct - It's just that at times you've written the same element multiple times.

Comment: @Shagchi Got it, so the answer $\{(), (123), (132)\}$ would be the correct, simplified answer, right?

Comment: @FernandoTorres yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

First of all, as I said in the comment above,

$$(123)=(231)=(312)$$

and

$$(132)=(213)=(321).$$

To find the centraliser of a permutation, there is a nice result: [conjugation by permutations preserves cyclic structure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/840008/104041)